# Recognize a shape in a image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing, photoshop-cs6

I have a folder with 10.000 images. 60.000 images of cars and 40.000 images of motorcycles.
I`m searching for a way to filter the images with some sort of shape/pattern recognition. The result that i want is: 2 folders, 1 with all the cars, and 1 with all the motorcycles.

Is this possible with photoshop? If so, how can i accomplish this? And if not, is there any software available where it ís possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that a readymade solution exists. AFAIK Visual Object Recognition is still a field of heavy research. The problem you describe could probably be tackled using existing techniques (similar to face recognition) but I don't think the problem is common enough that someone implemented this. If, then AFAIK not inside photoshop.
Notice I could be wrong, though.